# Trait for specifying a type parameter for Into::into

Tags: generics, rust, casting

There are occasionally times when it would be nice to be able to specify a type parameter for `Into::into`.

This doesn't happen very often—mostly just when you have a long-ish chain of method calls where the object type is changing. In that case, wrapping one part of the chain with `T::from`, or splitting it into multiple statements so you can specify the type in the variable binding would be kind of awkward.

I put together the following trait:

```
pub trait TypedInto {
    fn typed_into<T>(self) -> T where Self: Into<T> { self.into() }
}

impl<T> TypedInto for T {}
```

And I can now specify the type for `into`:

```
let clip = clips::table.find(id).first::<db::Clip>(&*conn)?
    .typed_into::<models::Clip>()
    .with_associations(&*conn)?;
```

Am I going to regret using this? This is in the context of an application rather than a library, so I don't necessarily need to worry about anyone other than myself reading it. Is this a bad habit? Should I just be more verbose?

Comment: One question per question, please. You are welcome to re-post the second half as a separate question.

Comment: @200_success, the second half wasn't really a second question; it was just more examples for my main question, which is whether "global" convenience functions like these are worth it in Rust. I think that question does belong here and may be specific to Rust; I haven't felt anxiety about doing things like this in other programming languages. My particular implementation of `typed_into` isn't even especially interesting or relevant.

Comment: On Code Review, we have concrete discussions about specific code. If you're looking for a general opinion on the value of global convenience functions, with these code samples serving merely as examples, that's too broad.

Comment: Why not just do `first::<models::Clip>` and avoid the transformation?

Comment: @Shepmaster, `db::Clip` is a struct for use with Diesel where each field maps directly to a database column. `models::Clip` is a slightly different  struct with additional fields (e.g., fields for a record's "associations"). It's just easier with Diesel to map to the DB struct and then expand from there.

Answer (score 1):

The most common way to handle type-hinting `Into::into` in stable Rust today is via temporaries. So for the use case you have here, I'd probably write something like:

```
let clip = {
    let clip: models::Clip = clips::table_find(id).first::<db::Clip>(&*conn)?.into();
    clip.with_associations(&*conn)?
};
```

But honestly, I don't think anyone will get up in arms about you using `TypedInto`. I know I've typed `.into::<Type>()` a couple times, and the common place you'd see the turbofish, `.collect::<Vec<_>>()`, is exactly this.

---

For this specific case, why don't you make a common `db::T` -> `model::T` conversion? It seems to be a common thing that happens, so making it explicit may be beneficial.

---

But that said, why don't we take a look at nightly feature gates? Because since 2015 the RFC for [Type Ascription](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0803-type-ascription.md) has been merged. It introduces an `expr : ty` syntax to the language meant to address cases like this. So rewriting your example to use type ascription,

```
let clip = ((clip::table.find(id)
    .first(&*conn)? : db::Clip)
    .into() : models::Clip)
    .with_associations(*&conn)?;
```

Unfortunately, the binding of type ascription, while the same as `as`, is lower than method call syntax (`.`), so the parenthesis are necessary (and rustfmt would probably *not approve* of the formatting I used here). There is [a patch](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/33380) written which would cause type ascription to bind more tightly than method calls, but it was closed in favor of waiting to later RFC the change (which would be backwards compatible (probably)).

There has been some recent noise around the feature, since it would make working with Futures a lot easier (though impl Trait may also help as well). Stabilization (since *it has been approved through RFC*) is blocked on ensuring soundness and allowing `&[1, 2, 3] : &[u8]` to work, so if you'd love to see type ascription stabilize, you can help with one of those.